# Class method returns None

Tags: python, class, return, return-value, return-type

I did a few modifications to the Bellman-Ford to get some data I need to compare but I can't seem to be able to get some of the information I need from the return the PrintArr method, while it prints the 'dist_list' the return won't take it nor am I being able to create the object using list comprehension either.

```
Class Graph:

def __init__(self, vertices):
    self.V = vertices
    self.graph = []

def addEdge(self, u, v, w):
    self.graph.append([u, v, w])
     
def printArr(self, dist, src):
    #print("Source  End     Distance")
    dist_list = []
    for i in range(self.V):
        #print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(src, i, dist[i]))
        #print(src, i, dist[i])
        dist_list.append([src, i, dist[i]])
    print(dist_list)
    print(dist_list == [[src, i, dist[i]] for i in range(self.V)])
    return [[src, i, dist[i]] for i in range(self.V)]

 
def BellmanFord(self, src):

    dist = [float("Inf")] * self.V
    dist[src] = 0

    for _ in range(self.V - 1):
        for u, v, w in self.graph:
            if dist[u] != float("Inf") and dist[u] + w < dist[v]:
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + w

    for u, v, w in self.graph:
        if dist[u] != float("Inf") and dist[u] + w < dist[v]:
            print("Graph contains negative weight cycle")
            return
                     
    self.printArr(dist, src)


matrix = [[0, 2, 2, 2, -1], [9, 0, 2, 2, -1], [9, 3, 0, 2, -1], [9, 3, 2, 0, -1], [9, 3, 2, 2, 0]]

g = Graph(len(matrix))


[[g.addEdge(i, j, element) for j, element in enumerate(array) if i != j] for i, array in enumerate(matrix)]

print(g.BellmanFord(0))
```

Output:

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, -1]]

True

None

Print: OK

List A = List B

Why return None??? What am I missing?

Comment: To understand this better, you could add more `print()` statements. For example, print out the method name at the start of each method. This will help you narrow down where the `None` comes from.

Comment: That None is coming from the PrintArr method, especifically from this line: return [[src, i, dist[i]] for i in range(self.V)]

Comment: "That None is coming from the PrintArr method, especifically from this line: return [[src, i, dist[i]] for i in range(self.V)] " No, it isn't. Think carefully about the logic: there are three calls to `print` in your program, and three lines of output, one from each. The `None` that confuses you is the last output, right? So, which call to `print` happens last? The `print(g.BellmanFord(0))` one, right? So, what is actually returning `None`? `g.BellmanFord(0)`, right? Now, why is that? Well, look at the `BellmanFord` method. Does it ever specify a value to `return`?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre] to learn how to track these issues down yourself.

Comment: As Karl says, you should look at the print statements. The line `return [[src, i, dist[i]] for i in range(self.V)]` doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `None` comes from:

```
print(g.BellmanFord(0))
```

`BellmanFord` never returns anything useful under any circumstances (it either falls off the end and implicitly returns `None`, or executes a plain `return`, which also return `None`). Remove the `print()` around the call, and you'll avoid the `None` output.

Alternatively, change `self.printArr(dist, src)` to `return self.printArr(dist, src)` so it *does* return something useful (assuming the early `return`, which should probably be raising an exception rather than silently returning `None`, isn't invoked).

Comment: Changing the self self.printArr(dist, src) to return self.printArr(dist, src) made it. Thanks mate.